# How to download an image from Json and store it in gallery?

Tags: android, android-json, android-json-rpc

I need to parse an image from some Json and STORE it on phone gallery . I have no idea how to save pictures on SD card so I need a code for this
thanks .

Comment: This is a completely unclear question. Well, is it a question actually? And it has absolutely nothing to do with MySQL Workbench. Update your question text to include more information, what you have done already and where you got stuck. Edit the tags to give your question some context (programmming language, phone OS etc.). Otherwise the question will be closed.

Comment: yes it is a question !

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. realy help you

public class ImageDownloadTask extends AsyncTask {

```
    CustomProgressBar progressDialog;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Drawable drawable;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = CustomProgressBar.show(UpdateActivity.this,
                "Loading...", true, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        URL url;
        InputStream in;

        BufferedInputStream buffIn;
        try {
            url = new URL(imageUrl);
            in = url.openStream();

            buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(in);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buffIn);
            drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        if (bitmap != null)
            imageViewPhoto.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
        else
            imageViewPhoto
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_default_photo);
    }
}
```